# Linux sandbox that shows which files have been created/modified

Tags: linux, sandbox

I use Gentoo Linux.
I need to find out what the program running under root downloads and where it puts the downloaded files.
I would also like to have a sandbox for testing programs from unreliable sources.

In particular, when installing the hplip driver, it downloads the plugin over the network. I would like to know which file it downloads and what changes it makes in the environment.

Please advise a sandbox program for Linux that would

1. It would allow you to run programs in a virtual environment.
2. It would use the current system configuration, i.e. that running programs in the sandbox would be identical to running outside the sandbox.
3. It would show which files were added or changed.
4. It would allow you to approve or reject changes if necessary. Like a commit in svn.
5. Different from VirtualBox and Vmware because they do not meet points 2-4

I tried to use firejail, but it does not contain points 3 and 4.
I also tried to use the sandbox, it similarly failed to implement point 3 and 4.
strace helps you keep track of all created and modified files, but unfortunately, it does not allow you to roll back changes.

In general, the most satisfying requirement of the mbox program is https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/archive/mbox/.
But unfortunately it is not in the Gentoo repository. At least I couldn't find it.

Comment: This question is off-topic here, but on-topic at Software Recommendations SE.  I've requested it to be migrated, or you can re-post it there.